# How to add inner ticks to a PieChart?

Tags: labeling, style, ticks, charts

I know how to add `Callouts` to the outside of a `PieChart`, but I would like to add inner ticks like this:

[image]

Note the 3, 6, 9, 12 ticks in the above image. Are there any simple options that I'm missing? Can ticks and inner callouts both be set?

Here's a MWE:

```
PieChart[{3, 4, 2, 3, 2}, SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 2},
 PlotRangePadding -> -10, ImagePadding -> -20, Frame -> False, 
 ImageMargins -> -10,
 ChartLabels -> Placed[{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}, "RadialCallout"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ticks = Join[Thread[{Range[π/2, 2 π, π/2], Reverse@Range[3, 12, 3], 
     {0, .05}}, List, 2], 
   Thread[{Complement[Range[π/6, 2 π- π/6, π/6], Range[π/2, 2 π, π/2]], "",
     {0, .02}}, List, 1]];
pc2 = First @ PieChart[{1, 1}, SectorOrigin -> {{0, 1}, 2}, 
   ChartStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[None]], 
   SectorSpacing -> {0, 0}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
   PolarAxes -> True, PolarTicks -> {ticks, None}, 
   PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, 1/10000}];
axis = pc2 /. t_Text :> (t /. Scaled[{0., 0.}, a_] :> Scaled[-.05 a, a]);

opts = Sequence[SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 2}, PlotRangePadding -> -10, 
   ImagePadding -> -20, Frame -> False, ImageMargins -> -10, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> Scaled[.04]}];
PieChart[{3, 4, 2, 3, 2}, opts, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}, "RadialCallout"], 
 Epilog -> axis]
```

[image]

A more convenient approach is to use [`ClockGauge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClockGauge.html) to create an angular axis:

```
ClearAll[angularAxis]
angularAxis[o:OptionsPattern[]][so_, t_: Range[3, 12, 3], tl_: {20, 12}, sd_: {12, 5}] :=
  {First[ClockGauge[{}, ScaleOrigin -> so, ScaleDivisions -> sd, o, "TickLengths" -> tl, 
      GaugeMarkers -> None, GaugeFrameStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[], White], 
      TicksStyle -> {Thick, Thin}, LabelStyle -> FontSize -> Scaled[.03]] /. 
    Text[a_, b___] :> Text[a /. Except[Alternatives @@ t] :> "", b]], 
   Circle[{0, 0}, so]};

PieChart[{3, 4, 2, 3, 2}, opts, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}, "RadialCallout"], 
 ImageSize -> Large, Epilog -> angularAxis[][2]]
```

[image]

Use

```
angularAxis["LabelSide"->Right, "TickSide"->Left, TicksStyle->Directive[Thin, Black]][2]
```

to get

[image]

and

```
Epilog -> angularAxis["LabelSide" -> Right, "TickSide" -> Left][1.5]
```

to get

[image]